# Filter object in Mongo database after items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I have one problem/question, how view Object from database using ng-repeat but filtering after item in this object e.g. I have ten object in `products` of title four computer, four TV two mobile. And my question how view this products using ng-repeat but filtering in title? I would like view separately products in different titles

Mongo Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var productSchema = new Schema({
imagePath: {
    type: String,
    require: true
},
title: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
},
subTitle: {
    type: String,
    require: true
},
newPrice: {
    type: Number,
    require : true,
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

controller function

```
 function getProducts() {
   User.getProducts().then(function(data){
     app.products = data.data.products; 
     console.log(data.data.products);
     app.loading = false;
   })
}
getProducts()
```

html view

```
<div ng-repeat="product in main.products" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10" >
  <div class="all_course_view slideanim">
    <div class="thumbnail image_course">
      <img src="../../uploads/{{ product.imagePath }}" alt="#"/>                    
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
      <h4>{{ product.subTitle }}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your results by title like so. [Curtosy of AngularJS Filter Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

HTML:

```
<p>Filter by Title: <input ng-model="search.title"></p>
<div ng-repeat="product in main.products | filter:search" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10" >
...
```